# Adding a dropdown arrow or triangle beside first button

Tags: html, css

In the below navigation bar

https://codepen.io/shaswat/pen/XzpRXL

how to create a down triangle or down-arrow beside home and when hover on home the triangle or arrow  should convert to upside .

1. cant change any html(input type , value etc) but you can add some element that should not break the navigation bar how its looking now
2. no bootstrap

HTML

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li ><input type=submit value=home>
     <ul>
         <li><input type=submit value=home1 /></li>
         <li><input type=submit value=home2 /></li>
         <li><input type=submit value=home3 /></li>
      </ul>


   </li>
   <li><input type=submit value=products class=active />

   </li>
   <li><input type=submit value=about />
   </li>
   <li><input type=submit value=Contact /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#cssmenu > ul ul input{
  border-top: 1px solid;  
}
#cssmenu input {
  padding: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  background: none;
    border-radius : 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
/* Menu CSS */#cssmenu,
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: black;  
  padding-bottom: 3px; 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#cssmenu:before,
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:before,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > input {
  padding: 12px 25px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;  
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #0d0d0d;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > input {
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active > input,
#cssmenu > ul > li > input.active {
  background: black;
  color:#fff;
}
/* Childs */
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #808080;
}
#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}

#cssmenu > ul ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li input {
  padding: 12px ;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li input:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid #d64e34;
  background: grey;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li input:active {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: why are using an `input` instead of `<a href="#"></a>`?

Comment: business requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast did it by myself , with HTML unicodes solution

https://codepen.io/shaswat/pen/XzpRXL

usin css only to make it transition between uparrow and downarrow

HTML

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li ><input type=submit value='Home'/>
     <div class="downArrow"> &#9660; </div>
     <div class="upArrow"> &#9650; </div>     
     <ul>
         <li><input type=submit value=home1 /></li>
         <li><input type=submit value=home2 /></li>
         <li><input type=submit value=home3 /></li>
      </ul>


   </li>
   <li><input type=submit value=products class=active />

   </li>
   <li><input type=submit value=about />
   </li>
   <li><input type=submit value=Contact /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#cssmenu > ul ul input{
  border-top: 1px solid;  
}
#cssmenu input {
  padding: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  background: none;
    border-radius : 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
/* Menu CSS */#cssmenu,
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: black;  
  padding-bottom: 3px; 
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#cssmenu:before,
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:before,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > input {
  padding: 12px 30px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;  
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #0d0d0d;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > input {
  background:violet;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active > input,
#cssmenu > ul > li > input.active {
  background: black;
  color:#fff;
}
/* Childs */
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #808080;
}
#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}

#cssmenu > ul ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li input {
  padding: 12px ;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li input[type=submit]:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid #d64e34;
  background: grey;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li input[type=submit]:active {
  background: green;
}

.downArrow { 
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 2px;  
    color:white;
}

.upArrow { 
  display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 2px;  
  color:white;    
}

#cssmenu li:first-child:hover .upArrow{
   display: block;
}

#cssmenu li:first-child:hover .downArrow{
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use font awesome icons class `fa-caret-up` and `fa-caret-down` 
and use javascript `onmousehover` and `onmouseout` functions to  toggle caret up and down.
**include font-awesome and jquery libs**

```
<a onmouseover="changecaretup()" onmouseout="changecaretdown()" >home <i id="caret" class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

java script

```
function changecaretup(){
$("#caret").removeClass("fa-caret-down");
$("#caret").addClass("fa-caret-up");

}

   function changecaretdown(){
    $("#caret").removeClass("fa-caret-up");
    $("#caret").addClass("fa-caret-down");

    }
```

Comment: using i tag , chagning the layout , also cant use bootstrap . thanks a lot for your input

Comment: Cant use any third party library

Comment: ok then download caret up and caret down png images and then onmousehover make the css property display  none to caret down image display block to caret up image ,onmouseout do opposite